# Differences between using 1d convolutions compared to 2d convolutions for timeseries

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, time-series, conv-neural-network

I have a timeseries that I want to use in a neural network for prediction. I now am using a 1d convolutional network for extracting the features from 3 channels as seen in the attached image. Now I have a question about what the differences are between using a 1d conv on the three series as compared to using a 2d convolutional network. I am thinking of converting the the 3 channels into three 2d images that are then used for a 2d conv network. I was thinking that a 2d network would have the ability to perceive the vertical location of a feature better because it now is on a 2d plane. A 1d convolution can only extract features based on the absolute values in the vector and not on a certain shape that can be at any height in the series.

I am unsure if this is the right way to interpret convolution networks, so I hope if there is anyone that could better explain the differences between the two methods that I have described.

[image: image of the time series]

Comment: What kind of data is this? 2D CNN is typically used for images because for image classification problems, there is almost always some relationship between horizontal and vertical features such as object boundaries. when you say you are going to convert the 3 channels into 2d images, what will the image look like?

Comment: I will convert the 3 lines you see into 3 images. So x axis is 3600 pixels and y axis is a resolution i specify, because the y axis is a floating point. So the neural network will see the same as you are seeing right now. I think that this will help the network with identifying patterns because it now also sees the position of a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully understanding your comment "I am thinking of converting the the 3 channels into three 2d images that are then used for a 2d conv network" but I kind of agree with rest of the thinking.

1D convolution: uses a filter/kernel window and moves that window over the input time-series to produce a new time-series. Depending on the learned parameters of the kernels, they act as feature extractors such as: moving averages, direction indicators, or detectors of patterns across time.

The advantage of a convolution is that it takes into account the "spatial" structure of the data. However, note that the multivariate time-series DO NOT have the same 2-dimensional data structures as image. Multivariate 1D data is not analogous to 2D univariate data. This is because the channels for the different variables to not have an inherent ordering like the samples along the time dimension do. Instead, the additional time series variables should be treated similarly to how you treat additional channels in image data, namely, with a stack of 1D kernels, rather than with a 2D kernel. Therefore, the 2D-CNN usage depends on your application.

Some applications of 2D convolutions on time-series data:

1. to utilize the additional information in [multi-variate](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/14/9/2392) time-series ([Other example](https://github.com/walesdata/2Dconv_pub/blob/master/gefcom_multiconv.ipynb)). This can also be done by considering different time-series as channels, similar to the different color signals.
2. Sezer and Ozbayoglu (2018) converted a time series into a 2D format to utilize CNNs to detect local patterns. They proposed [CNN-TA](https://github.com/omerbsezer/CNN-TA) that computes 15 technical indicators for different intervals and uses clustering to locate indicators that behave similarly close to each other in a 2D grid.
3. There is an interesting paper on the subject by Semenoglou et al (2023) "Image-based time series forecasting: A deep convolutional neural network approach"
4. Master's [thesis](https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/51463/1/TM_R%C3%BAben_Pereira.pdf) "2-D CNN FOR TIME SERIES TREND PREDICTION"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The second article you shared seems to look a lot like what I am searching for. I also want the neural network to look for patterns like in a stock market pattern seeking way. I thought that using just a 1d time series would be equivalent to a 2d one. But that seems to not be the case. I will try converting the series to images and see if it works better for my cause!